# MySQL query ! What's wrong here?

Tags: mysql

Please tell me what is wrong here :

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_verkauf_am`(`fld_kdnr`, `fld_artikelnummer`, `fld_artikelbez1`, `fld_saal_lst`, `fld_anzahl`, `fld_preis`) VALUES 
(900000, (SELECT `id`, `fld_besch_0`, `fld_class` FROM `tbl_saal_koord` WHERE `id` < 20300), 1, 50)
```

Comment: Why don't *you* tell *us* what's wrong? How are we supposed to know what's wrong if we don't know what it's supposed to do or what it actually is doing?

Comment: It's not valid SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `values` keyword and put all in one select

```
INSERT INTO tbl_verkauf_am (fld_kdnr, fld_artikelnummer, fld_artikelbez1, fld_saal_lst, fld_anzahl, fld_preis) 
SELECT 900000, id, fld_besch_0, fld_class, 1, 50
FROM tbl_saal_koord 
WHERE id < 20300
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query needs a little tweak.

syntax is :

```
INSERT INTO t1(col1, col2, ..., coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM this_table
```

Hence your query should be

```
INSERT INTO tbl_verkauf_am(fld_kdnr, fld_artikelnummer, fld_artikelbez1, fld_saal_lst, fld_anzahl, fld_preis) 
SELECT 900000,id, fld_besch_0, fld_class,1,50 
FROM tbl_saal_koord 
WHERE id < 20300
```